# Immutable helper - what is wrong with my React Native code

Tags: react-native, immutability

I try to set state's some parts with immutability-helper update function. But I am getting error: Unexpected token (57:95)

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const newlatlng = update(this.state, {markers: {latlng: {latitude: {$set: 40.3565}},{longitude: {$set: 27.977} } } } );          
this.setState(newlatlng);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to see the error if you indent your code. I think you have an extra set of `{`.

This

```
const newlatlng = update(this.state, {
  markers: {
    latlng: {
      latitude: {$set: 40.3565}
    },
    {
      longitude: {$set: 27.977 } 
    } 
  } 
});
```

Should be like below

```
const newlatlng = update(this.state, {
  markers: {
    latlng: {
      latitude: { $set: 40.3565 },
      longitude: { $set: 27.977 } 
    } 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, It is worked but I had to add a comma at ....$set: 40.3565 },

Comment: @EnginY. You are right. I'm sorry for the mistake. I'll fix it right away.